# Curiosities about the content of a rare book: Topological Vector Spaces by A. Grothendieck

Tags: reference-request, topological-vector-spaces

The book is a celebrated and highly influential book by A. Grothendeck, which was published in 1954, in French and for various reasons, it has been out of print since 1973. I am very much interested to learn from this book and but I can not afford its current high price. Unfortunately, neither the only mathematics library that I have access to holds any copy. Can anyone kindly advise me on how I can find out about the content of this invaluable book. The dream answer is a refreshed English lecture notes, or books, very closely following that book.

Many thanks.

Comment: I spent many ... hours with that book when I was a PhD student.  A fair amount of it is covered in TVS books such as that by Schaefer and that by Jarchow (if I've remembered the names right) but not *closely* as you ask for.

Comment: (Mind you, I was working from the French version which might go some way to explain why it wasn't *quite* the pleasant experience that it should have been!)

Comment: There is a translation into English by Chaljub. If you contact me (see user page) I might be able to assist you in finding it.